# SQL: Count/ sum columns within a specific date range

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, date-range

I have a table that roughly looks like this. There are thousands of rows.

```
booking_date   checkin_date    ...some other columns  ....    booking_value
22-mar-2016      29-mar-2016   ...........................         $150
01-apr-2016      17-may-2016   ...........................         $500
09-apr-2016      09-apr-2016   ...........................         $222
17-apr-2016      23-apr-2016  ...........................          $75
19-apr-2016      31-july-2016 ...........................          $690
03-May-2016      07-May-2016  .............................        $301
.
.
.
.
```

I am trying to calculate number of bookings per day and the value of bookings per day in April 2016. The second part is to calculate for how many bookings the booking_date and checking_date were the same.

I am very new to SQL. I can formulate the logic in paper, but can't seem to figure out how to proceed with the code.

Comment: Please tag your appropriate database name. Also add the script you are trying with and expected data.

Comment: The expected outcome would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(booking_date AS DATE), COUNT(*) as Number_of_Booking,
       SUM(CAST(booking_date AS DATE) = CAST(checkin_date AS DATE)) as count_with_same_date,
       SUM(booking_value) as booking_value
FROM t
WHERE booking_date >= '2016-04-01' AND
      booking_date < '2016-05-01'
GROUP BY CAST(booking_date AS DATE);
```

In particular, note the filtering on the dates.  The direct comparisons allow MySQL to use an index.

The calculation of the number on the same date uses a nice feature of MySQL where boolean values are treated as numbers in a numeric context.

Comment: @rahul . . . It is not just clean code.  It is the best way to write the query.  Being able to use indexes (and partitions) for filtering can be quite important.

Comment: I agree, happy to have learnt something. It was also very easy to understand for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below code-

```
SELECT CAST(booking_date AS DATE), 
COUNT(*) Number_of_Booking,
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(booking_date AS DATE)  
            = CAST(checkin_date AS DATE) THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
    END
) count_with_same_date,
SUM(booking_value) booking_value -- Booking value has to be Number field
FROM your_table
WHERE YEAR(booking_date ) = 2016
AND MONTH(booking_date ) = 4
GROUP BY CAST(booking_date AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. May I ask what should I include to find the number of bookings where booking date and checking date are the same within the same date range?

Comment: @rahul please check the new count calculation added in the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Oh... a confusion. The new calculation will also check daily. For example if there are 5 booking on 01-April-2016, it will count how many of them have same booking and check in date. May be 2 out of 5. Hope this is OK with you.

Comment: Yes, it's fine with me, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can try

```
Select booking_date
       ,count(*) as Number_of_bookings
       ,Sum(booking_value) as value
From table_name
Where booking_date between '01-apr-2016' and '30-apr-2016'
group by booking_date:
```

Or you can use month() and year() function in filter.

For the second question try,

```
Select booking_date
       ,checkin_date
       ,count(*)
from table_name
where booking_date=checkin_date
group by booking_date, checkin_date
```